# Should I use ServletDispatcher when trying to make an angular webapp, with no jsp pages?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have medium knowledge on how to make java webapps, and jsp pages. I am trying to extend my expertise, by learning how to use Spring MVC, AngularJS and RESTful api's.

I am having trouble drawing the lines between the dots. First of all, from what I have read, there should be no real need for jsp pages, when trying to do pure angularJS. So I'm trying to not use jsp's this time.

I am pretty much trying to make two html-pages, each with a link to the other. Now in a completely basic Spring MVC setup, this would be done with the help of two controllers, and the ServletDispatcher. In the servlet-context.xml (default name) I could probably change the default suffix from .jsp to .html, but I have read that I should treat static html pages as resources, instead of views, as they do not need the powers of a servlet.

The thing is, I have never made any kind of web page which didn't utilize a dispatcher, or front controller servlet, and although it might be completely obvious to most, I do not know what the alternative is. I am very in doubt if I am supposed to use the ServletDispatcher at all, and what the alternative is. I kinda thought the ServletDispatcher, and front controller pattern implementation was one of the most central parts of Spring...

So should I use the ServletDispatcher for an Angular web application, or should I just use Spring to make the RESTful api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring framework allows you to serve static resources using `ResourceHttpRequestHandlers` which stores registrations of resource handlers for serving static resources such as images, css files and others through Spring MVC including setting cache headers optimized for efficient loading in a web browser. Resources can be served out of locations under web application root, from the classpath, and others.

Since you already have a basic spring MVC setting and running, then you need to configure your angularJS-app as a static resources, you can choose to keep your angularJS application folder under webapp folder, and continues your angularJS development there and you don`t need any JSP there.

Configure `ResourceHttpRequestHandlers`
**with XML**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/app/**" location="/app/"/>
```

**with Java config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("/app/");
  }
}
```

Now you can access your angularJS app as http://localhost:8080/context-root/app/

Your API development will continue as well in your spring MVC controllers.

Here is a great youtube series of [Web Development Using Spring and AngularJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sc2atFv_h_I)

Comment: My first impression of this is very good. I think I have caught a misunderstanding of my own. I have been thinking of AngularJS as part of an app, and not as the language I would use to code an actual complete app. Will this approach package my angular app within a war, when my Spring MVC is set to package as a war?

Comment: Will this approach package my angular app within a war - Yes

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't actually think I will use this approach, but you cleared up a major misunderstanding I had, and also presented a good solution. I think I need to investigate more on how (if?) angular apps are structured, packaged and deployed to a server now. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad that I could help,  here is the `angular-seed project` to start with  if you want to go that route, https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Comment: Thanks. Once I realized my misconception, it was a lot easier to find relevant resources online, but I'll make sure to check your link out as soon as I am done reading my current find :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use AngularJS to make static web pages(HTML+CSS+JS+other static resources).
2. Use Servlet to make RESTful API.(Restlet framework is recommended to make RESTful API, it can run as a standalone java app or integrate into Servlet to run in Tomcat.)
3. JS will call RESTful API to get data and update the page view.

Comment: How do I structure, package and/or deploy the static resources? Previously I have always packaged everything in a war-file, and deployed it as a single application.

Comment: Simply use nginx to serve the static resources. See AngularJS's sample.